# How to run exe file using Installshield?

Tags: installshield

I have small doubt about Installshield.

While creating `exe` file using Installshield , I want to check if version path exists or not. If it does not, want to extract `.exe` file.

How can I call and run `exe` file?
How to give its path?
Which function we have to use to call to install `exe` file?

Comment: an external exe or the one you're installing? Try [helpnet](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield17helplib/IHelpLaunchEXE.htm)

Comment: I will give exe which i want to install.